# I must need to open two connections to execute two different queries?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, sqldataadapter

Currently I am executing two queries against two different tables and getting this exception,

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

This is what I am trying to do,

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["userID"].ToString());
        string deleteStatement = "Delete from Table1 where userID=@userID";
        string deleteStatement2 = "Delete from Table2 where userID=@userID";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement2, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
                int result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (result2 == 1)
                {
                    BindData();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am doing this because Table2 has `userID` as foreign key and must be deleted before deleting user actually

Comment: Consider cascading deletes on your FK relationships.

Comment: How can I do that sir, actually I will try to google it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling `Open()` twice. You can remove the second call `Open()`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["userID"].ToString());
    string deleteStatement = "Delete from Table1 where userID=@userID";
    string deleteStatement2 = "Delete from Table2 where userID=@userID";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement2, connection))
        {
            // connection.Open(); // remove this line
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
            int result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result2 == 1)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `connection.Open()` is not required as it will be open from first statement.

Still to be on the safer side, you can use

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    connection.Open();
```

Comment: It will *always* be open already, so this will always be false.  Why bother?

Answer (score 1):

The second `connection.Open();` doesn't need to be there.  The first one is enough; as the error message says, it's already open.

One connection can perform multiple queries, with only a single call to `Open`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
  {
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["userID"].ToString());
    string deleteStatement = "Delete from Table1 where userID=@userID";
    string deleteStatement2 = "Delete from Table2 where userID=@userID";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS()))
    {
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
      using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(deleteStatement2, connection))
        {
            cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
            int result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result2 == 1)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile.  With this change the connection is now out of scope by the time you try to create the second command.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["userID"].ToString());
        string deleteStatement = "Delete from Table1 where userID=@userID";
        string deleteStatement2 = "Delete from Table2 where userID=@userID";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = deleteStatement;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", userID));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            cmd.CommandText = deleteStatement2;
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result == 1) BindData();
        }
    }
```